# Rotated and scaled grid doesn't show up properly

Tags: tikz-pgf

I was working on some pictures when I found this issue, I think it might be a bug.
When you change the scale factor to 1, it solves itself, but I was wondering if there was another workaround to this.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=2.5]
\coordinate (A) at (0,1);
\begin{scope}[rotate around={-30:(0,1)}]
\coordinate (G) at (2,0);
\draw (A) grid (G);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: image of the issue]

Comment: I'm not sure it's a bug (which of course should be reported at https://sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs), seems like a question of numerical inaccuracies. If you place `A` at `(0,1.001)` and `G` at `(2.001,0)`, the grid shows up as expected.

Comment: @TorbjørnT., isn't that the answer already? Another way to prove it is to change `2.5`to `2.4`, `2` and so on (the grid changes for each value). Maybe the question could be changed to something like "Is there a way to enchance PGF numerical precision?"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, I'm not sure it's a bug (which of course should be reported at sourceforge.net/p/pgf/bugs), might seem like a question of numerical inaccuracies. If you place `A` at `(0,1.001)` and `G` at `(2.001,0)`, the grid shows up as expected.

Changing both unit vectors (and the `step` for the `grid`) to 2.5cm, as in the second `tikzpicture` below, is another workaround.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,scale=2.5]
\coordinate (A) at (0,1.001);
\begin{scope}[rotate around={-30:(0,1)}]
\coordinate (G) at (2.001,0);
\draw (A) grid (G);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,x=2.5cm,y=2.5cm,step=2.5cm]
\coordinate (A) at (0,1);
\begin{scope}[rotate around={-30:(0,1)}]
\coordinate (G) at (2,0);
\draw (A) grid (G);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```